# Accessing entitys' components tanks fps

Tags: c++, entity, frame-rate

The FPS problem I am facing occurs when I try to access an entity's component with lines like these:

```
SpriteComponent* sprite = (SpriteComponent*) entity_pointer->getComponent("Sprite");
PositionComponent* position = (PositionComponent*) entity_pointer->getComponent("Position");
```

getComponent(component name) returns a component pointer which can be turned into the derived component class.

I've commented out bits and pieces of my code and I've determined that lines like these take my FPS down a notch especially when I have created many entities.

To give a rundown on how I've poorly setup my entity component system: I have a group of controller pointers that hold entity pointers that hold component pointers. Each controller does a certain thing to an entity given it has the right components such as the physics controller advancing the position of an entity using the velocity given by the physics component. The different controller classes are all derived from the Controller class and the different components are derived from the Component class.

Now I am new to C++ and pointers for that matter so I hope I set it up right. What about these two lines could slow my game down by so much? Does anything jump out at you?

Comment: The way FPS are defined, doing a tiny bit of work could drastically lower FPS, for example from a few thousand to a few hundred, even though whatever you did only took a few nanoseconds, i.e. a tiny fraction of the frame budget at your *target* FPS. How much *time* did it take? And what does `getComponent` do - how does it look up the component pointer, which kind of data structure does it access (e.g. unsorted array, sorted array, hash table, BST, etc.)?

Comment: How do you search for your component? Is it O(n) complexity or do you have it stored in std::map?

Comment: unordered_map<string,Component*> component_list;

Comment: get component returns the comp pointer at the string so:
 return component_list.at(myCompName);

Comment: That looks harmless enough. Do those lines happen to be in a loop over all entities or something? But like remote debugging, remote profiling is pretty fruitless - one needs the full code at least to make anything better than educated guesses. (And you still didn't provide *absolute* timings, or at least FPS before-after numbers, so I'm not yet convinced there is a performance problem at all.)

Comment: Without the draw code I run at 1000~ fps and with the draw code im at about less than 100~fps. Each controller loops over all its entities once and each controller must run the line I think is slowing me down.

Comment: 1000 FPS down to 100 FPS means it previously took 1ms and now takes 10ms. So you didn't lose 900 FPS, you lost 9ms. Besides, how many entities and how many controllers do you have? Anyway, if *all* you did was just execute these two lines once per entity per controller, with a realistic number of entities and controllers, that would be troublesome. Have you profiled and determined which parts exactly take the majority of those 9ms?

Comment: It must be the getComponent function. But what is to be done? I need to make my component finding faster. What could be an alternative to storing Component Pointers in an unordered map if i still want to find them by a string?

Comment: I already told you, remote optimizing is an exercise in futility. Only you have access to the source code, the data necessary to run benchmarks, knowledge of the architecture, etc. all of which are necessary to think of an alternate implementation and determine whether it's any faster. At best, we can tell you some steps which may help you get started. The first is getting **cold, hard data** (profiler output) that the hotspot is where you think it is, based on a representative run of the *real* code, not some stripped-down version. The rest depends on said data and on your code base.